# Calculate data in a second column using data from the first one

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a SQL query which calculates some data.
For instance, I have such SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM FIRMS WHERE FIRM_ID IN(....) GROUP BY FIRM;
```

which produces such data:

```
28,740,573
30,849,923
25,665,724
43,223,313
34,334,534
35,102,286
38,556,820
19,384,871
```

Now, in a second column I need to show relation between one entry and sum of all entries. Like that:

```
28,740,573 | 0.1123
30,849,923 | 0.1206
25,665,724 | 0.1003
43,223,313 | 0.1689
34,334,534 | 0.1342
35,102,286 | 0.1372
38,556,820 | 0.1507
19,384,871 | 0.0758
```

For instance, sum of all entries from first column above is gonna be `255,858,044` and the value in a first entry, second cell is gonna be `28,740,573 / 255,858,044 = 0.1123`. And same for each entry in a result.

How can I do that?

UPD: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I forgot to DBMS. It's Oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, Oracle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most databases now support the ANSI standard window functions.  So, you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT),
       SUM(AMOUNT) / SUM(SUM(AMOUNT)) OVER () as ratio
FROM FIRMS
WHERE FIRM_ID IN (....)
GROUP BY FIRM;
```

Note:  Some databases do integer division.  So, if `AMOUNT` is an integer, then you need to convert to a non-integer number in these databases.  One easy method is to multiple by 1.0.

Comment: Oracle provides even a built-in function for that: `RATIO_TO_REPORT(AMOUNT) OVER () as ratio`, see  [RATIO_TO_REPORT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions124.htm)